# ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete error using Context Injection

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been following an old selenium tutorial and I can't execute the program because of this error.
This is my code:

```
namespace ProductAutomation.Utils.Hooks
{
    [Binding]
    public class ScenarioHooks
    {
        private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

        public ScenarioHooks(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }
        

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void StartWebDriver()
        {
            if (_scenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Chrome"))
            {
                DriverController.Instance.StartChrome("--disable-extensions");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete. Please get the ScenarioContext via Context Injection.
>
> ScenarioContext.Current cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Does if (_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Chrome")) work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
if (_scenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Chrome"))
```

With:

```
if (_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Chrome"))
```

I would suggest also to get the DriverContext via ContextInjection.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete. How to get ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title and ScenarioContext.Current.StepInfo.Text](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1762)
- [ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete. How to use Context Injection](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1468)

---

### tl; dr

You can find the detailed documentation in [ScenarioContext](https://specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/)

Comment: Yes it worked! But can you explain why I don't need Current?

Comment: @Xcecution Updated the answer with the links to the relevant documentation and discussions.